# Why is CATransform3D not working when triggered from viewWillAppear?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios, catransform3d

In `viewWillAppear` I want to adjust some of my views using the following transformation (Monotouch code):

```
CATransform3D oTransform3D = CATransform3D.Identity;
oTransform3D.m34 = 1.0f / -400;
oTransform3D = oTransform3D.Translate( 110, 0, 0);
oTransform3D = oTransform3D.Rotate( (-70f) * (float)Math.PI / 180f, 0, 1, 0);
```

However, this causes the view to be rendered far left of the screen.
If I put the very same code in `viewDidAppear`, it is working.
I have already checked that all views have valid sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever figure this out?  I've run into a similar situation where a 3D transform refuses to behave when applied to an immediate subview of a UIViewController's root view.  A workaround for me was to wrap the subview in another container UIView.

Something along these lines:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
    container.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:container];

    self.myCrazyFlippingSpinningView = [[CrazyFlippingSpinningView alloc] init];
    [container addSubview:self.myCrazyFlippingSpinningView];
}
```

Of course, I'd prefer to *not* have to do that.  It's such a hack.  If anyone's encountered this and has a better solution, I'd love to see it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand the question but I am going to take a swag.

CATransform3D has a vanishing point that transforms refer to.  The vanishing point is always the x,y center point of whatever view you place the transformed view onto.  When I was struggling through the 3D transform issues and getting unexpected results, it was always solved by simply making sure I knew the size and center point of the container view.

You say your code works in ViewDidLoad...does that mean you are adding a transformed view to the base view?  like: this.View.AddSubview(yourTransformedView); ??

I mean, I don't think your problem is a matter of ViewWillAppear vs. ViewDidLoad; I am going to guess that if I saw the code where you apply your transform to the views and then add your views to a base view or some other superview, I would be able to quickly tell you what is happening.

Comment: I have a UIViewController. To this controller's view I add a subview. To this subview I apply the transformation above. This transformation is working as expected if I place the code above in viewDidAppead. However if I put it in viewWillAppear the result is different/wrong. I would like to understand why. AFAIK in viewWillAppear all views are in position and have their final sizes already.

Comment: ViewDidLoad happens 1 time when the ViewController is first used.  ViewWillAppear happens every time the view is recalled by, say, navigating away from it...then back again.  My suggestion is to try placing your code block in ViewDidLoad as the very last thing that happens in the chance that somewhere else in your ViewDidLoad code you are moving or changing something that relates to the base view.